# Haskell createProcess and read from Handle

Tags: haskell, handle, createprocess, smt

when i use Haskell [createProcess](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Process.html) do i need to fork before as if i was using exec in c?

From the example's i have seen and for what i have tried i don't think i do but if i read from the output Handle once i get the expected result but if i try to read twice it doesn't read even once.

For example:

beginProcess is the same as createProcess and z3 is a smt solver that reads from stdin and writes to stdout.

```
execute :: Process -> String -> IO String
execute (Just std_in, Just std_out,_,_) cmd = do
  hPutStr std_in cmd 
  hFlush std_in
  hGetLine std_out

main :: IO()
main = do 
  proc <- beginProcess "z3" ["-smt2","-in"]
  execute proc "(set-option :print-success true)" >>= print
  execute proc "(set-option :print-success true)" >>= print
```

If i do one execute i get the expected result, but if i do both nothing happens.
Am i reading or writing wrong to the handles ?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Please show your imports. In particular, what is `beginProcess`? I can't find it on hoogle or hayoo.

Comment: The `process` library is very system dependent so you should include what platform you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a hunch that you are ["suffering from buffering"](https://www.google.com/search?q=suffering+from+buffering).

Note that you are not emitting any newlines to the z3 process. Also, z3 may not be flushing its output after every command.

The best way to interact with a terminal program is through a pseudo tty.  Here is an explanation of how such a set up would work: http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html

Comment: I forgot the newline xD. Now it's working and i didnt know about pseudo tty, so thank you for your answer.